# Implement nand only by = and !=

Tags: java, boolean

I run this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        boolean a = false;
        boolean b = true;
        xor(a,a);
        xor(a,b);
        xor(b,a);
        xor(b,b);
    }

    public static void xor(boolean a , boolean b){
        System.out.println(a + "\t" + b + "\t" + (a != b));
    }
```

and got this output :

```
false   false   false
false   true    true
true    false   true
true    true    false
```

**UPDATE**
as you know nand truth-table is :

```
false   false   true
false   true    true
true    false   true
true    true    false
```

how to return nand only using = or != operators without conditional || and &&?

Comment: well try to answer to the quesrion is false different from false? I guess it is not :)

Comment: U need just some concentration!, Of course `false != false` returns `false` since `false = false`\

Comment: i confused when working with nand , xor ...!!! i edited the question!

Comment: You asked one thing, then changed your question to ask something else entirely. That's not really appropriate. At worst it invalidates all the answers and results in unjustified downvotes of those answers, and most likely a few downvotes for you as well. Either you should ask them as separate questions, or you should start by asking what you actually want to know.

Comment: It makes me want to give up using Stack Overflow when people do things like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing **nand** without && and ||?

Try:

```
a ? !b : true;
```

As in:

```
public static void nand(boolean a , boolean b){
    System.out.println(a + "\t" + b + "\t" + (a ? !b : true));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Basically because `false == false` returns true.
False is not not equal to false, because false is equal to false.

If you are familiar with binary operations: it is like the binary XOR operation

```
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
0 XOR 0 = 0 << this is false != false
```

edit: for the NAND:

```
a ? !b : true;
```

a is evaluated, if a is true NOT b is the result, so if b is false, the result will be true and if b is true, the result will be false. In case of a being false the result is always true.

Comment: Or if you can use 'not' operator: (!a || !b)

Answer (score 2):

use this function it is the implementation of nand gate

```
public boolean nand(boolean input1, boolean input2){
    return !(input1 && input2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's one way...

```
return String.format("%b%b", a, b).length() != 8; // only "truetrue" has length 8
```

Of course internally `String.format` will do a lot of things you forbid in the question...

---

Here's another way, which uses `if` instead of conditional, if your only condition is not using other *operators*:

```
if (a == false) return true; // (a==false && b==false) || (a==false && b==true)
if (b == false) return true; // (a==true && b==false)
return false;                // (a==true && b==true)
```

However, `NAND` does have two independent inputs, which you need to somehow test and combine: `a` is not true *and* `b` is not true. There's no way to get around this being two conditions, you can only obfuscate the fact with different tricks or use library functions in different ways to push this out of your own code.

---

Third way, in C you could do this: `return (int)a + (int)b != 2;` or other similar operations on booleans interpreted as integers, but casting booleans to integers is not allowed in Java so for equivalent code you'd have to use (for example) `?:` operator to convert boolean to integer. You could of course wrap this in a method, so then in java you could have `return myBoolToInt(a) + myBoolToInt(b) != 2;`, if just hiding the operation is ok, and you'd be ok with useing `+`...